# Is Facebook's /me/permissions an undocumented Graph API call?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After looking for ways to check if a user has a given permission, I stumbled upon some obscure reference to /me/permissions, which, lo and behold, works!

For the life of me, I can't find the documentation on the Facebook Documentation - is it deprecated, or simply undocumented?

Given how often facebook changes things, should I even be using this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They [blogged](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/495/) about that:

> As part of our efforts to transition
>   functionality from legacy REST APIs to
>   the Graph API, we added the ability to
>   retrieve the list of permissions users
>   have granted your app by adding the
>   permissions connection to the User
>   object.

And is part of the docs on the [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object, under connections.